# how to aggs inner nested object element for elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

We have the data like below:

```
{
    "fieldA": "A",
    "fieldB": "B",
    "object": [{
            "name": "A",
            "value": 50000
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to groupby fieldA aggregation(order by desc) sum object.value. Actualy. we only have one  element for  all data. 
previous I can aggregate the valueA not in the array object.
I have tried the plain script like below:

```
{
    "size":0,
    "aggs":{
        "terms_fielda":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"fieldA"
            },
            "aggs":{
                "group_sum":{
                    "sum":{
                        "field":"object.valueA"
                    }
                },
                "sort_by":{
                    "bucket_sort":{
                        "sort":[
                            {"group_sum": {"order": "desc"}}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I implement the inner nested object sum?
Below is the mapping:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "fieldA": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "fieldB": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "car": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea on the nested object aggregation. Could anyone can help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which datatype has the object field?

Comment: What have you tried so far and have you checked the aggregation module in the Elastic documentation first?

Comment: I have tried the basic function of aggregation and aggregation of aggegation. any idea on the inner object aggregation?

Comment: I also updated the mapping.